# Display all employees in a select box with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.net core 3.1

On my create page the code below shows all employees in a select box.

EmployeeId is the foreign key of the Identity id.

But on my edit page I receive an error message:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> FormatException: **Input string was not in a correct format.**
> System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)

```
<div class="col-5">
  <select asp-for="Model.Checklists.EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId" id="EmployeeId" asp-items="Model.User.ToSelectListItem(Convert.ToInt32(Model.Checklists.EmployeeId))" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
```

The model:

```
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public virtual IdentityUser User { get; set; }
```

The viewmodel:

```
public IEnumerable<IdentityUser> User { get; set; }
```

The code in my controller:

```
    // GET - EDIT
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if(id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        ChecklistVM.Checklists = await _db.Checklist.Include(m => m.Customer).Include(m => m.CustomerSite).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        ChecklistVM.CustomerSite = await _db.CustomerSite.Where(s => s.CustomerId == ChecklistVM.Checklists.CustomerId).ToListAsync();


        if (ChecklistVM.Checklists == null)
        {
            NotFound();
        }

        return View(ChecklistVM);
    }
```

ToSelectListItem method:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Checklist.Extensions
{
    public static class IEnumerableExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItem<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int selectedValue)
        {
            return from item in items
                   select new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Text = item.GetPropertyValue("Name"),
                       Value = item.GetPropertyValue("Id"),
                       Selected = item.GetPropertyValue("Id").Equals(selectedValue.ToString())
                   };
        }
    }
}
```

GetPropertyValue method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Checklist.Extensions
{
    public static class ReflectionExtension
    {
        public static string GetPropertyValue<T>(this T item, string propertyName)
        {
            return item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(item, null).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to return all employees (displaying their name), and the selected item should be the one that was submitted on the create page.

I am not sure why it works on my create page, but fails on the edit page.

Comment: The model has `EmployeeId` as type `string` but you're using `Convert.ToInt32` with that value. Sounds like the string is not a valid integer.

Comment: The identities ID's look like this: "249daf22-ca87-4eaa-8be2-dec2d46b2079"
So it is true that it is a string, and I understand that this can't convert to an integer.
But .ToSelectListItem requires integers.

I am really confused about how it can work in the first place on the create page with the same code.

Comment: ToSelectListItem is this method written by you?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, it is a custom method, sorry about that, I have now included the code in my post.

Comment: So it is clear that you can not use this method with `Guid` passed to it. So either you should create a new method which accepts `Guid` as parameter and use it. OR you can create an instance of `SelectList` using `Model.User` separately and then assign it to `asp-items`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Awesome, that did the trick. Thanks, I just completely overlooked that method because it worked on another page. But does anyone have any idea why it works for the create page, there is nothing different I did there, and it could convert it to an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @ChetanRanpariya in the comments.

> So it is clear that you can not use this method with Guid passed to it. So either you should create a new method which accepts Guid as parameter and use it.

I made the method:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListGuid<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string guid)
    {
        return from item in items
               select new SelectListItem
               {
                   Text = item.GetPropertyValue("Name"),
                   Value = item.GetPropertyValue("Id"),
                   Selected = item.GetPropertyValue("Id").Equals(guid)
               };
    }
```

And changed the view:

```
<div class="col-8">
  <select asp-for="Checklists.EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId" id="EmployeeId" asp-items="Model.User.ToSelectListGuid(Model.Checklists.EmployeeId)" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
```